# How can i make the bot reply to a message which is a reply by me discord

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, reply

Like if I sent a message replying to a bot message, i want the bot to react to it
Language I use => Javascript!

Comment: You should provide code that you tried using and the problems that you encountered.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this is how you would do that

```js
if (!message.author.bot && message.type === 'REPLY' && message.mentions.repliedUser.id === client.user.id) {
    message.react('')
}
```